# What is controller[:id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My book says to run "rails g controller sessions" and edit it as

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

What is session[:user_id]? If X is controller, Y and Z are some string, can I define as X[:Y] = Z?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be a key on a controller like X[:Y] implies. Imagine you created a variable `store = {}`. You would then say `store[:user_id] = user.id`. Now you have `store = {:user_id: theusersid}`. The session variable is just a store with additional keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session[:user_id] is a special variable, that can be accessed like a hash,, storing all information you store into your application's session.

You can read more about the session in Rails here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

It's basically a Hash that's shared between requests to store information and re-use it in sub-sequent requests.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session has more details about how rails works with sessions.

Answer (score 0):

session[:user_id] is a variable, that you earlier need to store and then reuse it throughout your session.
F.e. You have authentication and then you have to jump through pages, that needs user_id. So you can use session, to store it there. You can find more info there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html.

Answer (score 0):

No. `session` is just an object which respond to `[](key)` method. You cannot define something like `controller[:foo] = 'bar'`